# Creating and printing the Dictionary content from entered user input

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I learnt basic concepts of List, Tuples and Dictionaries along with conditional statement. And started writing simple piece of code to accept the User Input and create the Dictionary from entered inputs and print the Dictionary content.

The code is written -

```
patientCount = 0

noOfPatients = input("\nHow many Patient's to Admit: ")

while (patientCount < int(noOfPatients)):
    print("\nEnter the Details of the Patient {} :".format(patientCount+1))
    patientFirstName = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the FIRST NAME: "))
    patientLastName = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the LAST NAME: "))
    patientMRN = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the MRN: "))
    patientGender = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the GENDER (M/F/O): "))
    patientBirthYear = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the BIRTH YEAR: "))
    patientAge = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the AGE: "))

    patientCount +=1
```

---

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
How many Patient's to Admit ?: 2

Enter the Details of the Patient 1 :

    Enter the FIRST NAME: David
     Enter the LAST NAME: John
           Enter the MRN: 878783
Enter the GENDER (M/F/O): M
Enter the BIRTH YEAR (YYYY): 1901
          Patient AGE is: 117 Years
-------------------------

Enter the Details of the Patient 2 :

    Enter the FIRST NAME: Sam
     Enter the LAST NAME: Tommy
           Enter the MRN: 76487236
Enter the GENDER (M/F/O): F
Enter the BIRTH YEAR (YYYY): 1990
          Patient AGE is: 28 Years
```

Created an initial empty dictionary as -

```
patientDatabase = {}
```

I want to create the nested dictionary as below from above entered inputs in the code-

```
patientDatabase = { 
Patient 1:{'First Name':'David', 'Last Name': 'John', 
'MRN': 878783, 'Gender': 'M', BirthYear': 1901, 'Age': 117}, 
Patient2:{'First Name':'Sam', 'Last Name': 'Tommy', 
'MRN': 76487236, 'Gender': 'F', BirthYear': 1990, 'Age': 28} }
```

And the when the above dictionary is printed, the OUTPUT I'm looking for as below -

```
Patient 1 Details:
--------------------
FIRST NAME: David
 LAST NAME: John
       MRN: 878783
    GENDER: M
BIRTH YEAR: 1901
       AGE: 117 Years

Patient 2 Details:
--------------------
FIRST NAME: Sam
 LAST NAME: Tommy
       MRN: 76487236
    GENDER: F
BIRTH YEAR: 1990
       AGE: 28 Years
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    noOfPatients = input("\nHow many Patient's to Admit: ")
    patient_db=dict()
    for i in range(int(noOfPatients)):
        patien_details=dict()    
        print("\nEnter the Details of the Patient {} :".format(patientCount+1))
        patien_details["FirstName"] = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the FIRST NAME: "))
        patien_details["LastName"] = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the LAST NAME: "))
        patien_details["MRN"] = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the MRN: "))
        patien_details["Gender"] = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the GENDER (M/F/O): "))
        patien_details["BirthYear"] = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the BIRTH YEAR: "))
        patien_details["Age"] = input("{:>30}".format("Enter the AGE: "))
        patient_db[i+1]=patien_details

    for k,v in patient_db.items():
        print(k,v)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Veera for the information. Learnt that, using the Variables (which I'd used earlier) itself as Keys of the dictionary.